# find all '#' and wrap in span in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, str-replace

I have a message that I need to find all '#' and wrap in a span tag, to apply a class.  My JavaScript currently only works if there is one single '#'.

How can I loop over my array returned by the `findHashTag` function without duplicating the message?

For example with the message: `'Hi today its sunny out #sun #summer'`

I want it to be returned from my function like

`'Hi today its sunny out <span class="hash">#sun</span> <span class="hash">#summer</span>'`

```
$scope.formatMessage = function (message) {
      var findHashTag = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g,
          tagMatch = message.match(findHashTag),
          hashReplace ='<span class="hash">' + tagMatch + '</span>',

      message = message.replace(tagMatch, hashReplace);

      return message;
};
```

Note: I am using AngularJs!

Comment: That's an awfully complex regex. I think you want this: `/\b#[a-z0-9]+/i`

Comment: Just have to do `message.replace(expr, '<span class="hash">#$1</span>')`

Comment: PSL is right, but I would use @meagar 's regex, still need to add the `g` qualifier `/\b#[a-z0-9]+/ig`

Comment: what is the `#$1` doing in the `<span>` tag?

Comment: That's a reference to a match

Comment: @m.e.conroy is right, so combining them you could do `.replace(/(#[a-z0-9]+)/g, '<span class="hash">$1</span>')` Try out `'#test Hi today its sunny out #sun #summer'.replace(/(#[a-z0-9]+)/g, '<span class="hash">$1</span>')`